# OpenGL glfw cannot draw points

Tags: c++, opengl, opencl, glfw

I followed a tutorial [OpenCL path tracing tutorial 3: OpenGL viewport, interactive camera and defocus blur](http://raytracey.blogspot.com/2017/01/opencl-path-tracing-tutorial-3-opengl.html). He used GLUT to generate a window while I tried switching all glut stuffs to GLFW. But glfw failed to draw points in vbo and I don't know why. The window can be set to a certain color but no points appear.

Here is my draw() function:

```
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f, 1.0f); // blue
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(0.0f, image_width, 0.0f, image_height);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 16, 0); // size [2, 3, 4], type, stride, pointer
glColorPointer(4, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 16, (GLvoid*) 8); // size [3, 4], type, stride, pointer

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, image_width * image_height);
glDisableClientState(GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
```

used in GLFW render loop:

```
cpu_spheres[6].position.s[1] += 0.01;
queue.enqueueWriteBuffer(cl_spheres, CL_TRUE, 0, num_sphere*sizeof(mySphere), cpu_spheres);
// args order in kernel is diff from tutorial
kernel.setArg(4, cl_spheres);
kernel.setArg(5, myHash(num_frame));

runKernel();

draw(); // cannot draw points

glfwSwapBuffers(gWindow);
```

Here is my OpenGL init code:

```
if (!glfwInit()) {
    std::cerr << "GLFW initialization failed" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GL_TRUE);

gWindow = glfwCreateWindow(image_width, image_height, APP_TITLE, NULL, NULL);
if (gWindow == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to create GLFW window" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();
    return false;
}

glfwMakeContextCurrent(gWindow);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize GLEW" << std::endl;
    return false;
}

glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
gluOrtho2D(0.0f, image_width, 0.0f, image_height);
```

runKernel is all the same as it is in the tutorial:

```
std::size_t global_work_size = image_width * image_height;
std::size_t local_work_size  = kernel.getWorkGroupInfo<CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE>(device);

if (global_work_size % local_work_size != 0)
    global_work_size = (global_work_size / local_work_size + 1) * local_work_size;

// Make sure OpenGL is done using VBOs
glFinish();

queue.enqueueAcquireGLObjects(&cl_vbos);
queue.finish();

// Launch the kernel
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NullRange, global_work_size, local_work_size);
queue.finish();

// Release VBOs so OpenGL can use them
queue.enqueueReleaseGLObjects(&cl_vbos);
queue.finish();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem with your code is that you tell GLFW to create OpenGL 3.3 Core profile. Core profile contexts do not support legacy APIs, such as client vertex arrays (`glVertexPointer`, `glEnableClientState`, etc.). Assuming that there are no other problems, you should be able to make it work by changing `GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE` to `GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE`, or alternatively, removing all calls to `glfwWindowHint`.

Comment: Removing all glfwWIndowHint calls works. Setting or changing flags results to a seg signal.